Position Orientation Line in QField
There is a little blue triangle on my GPS point in QField. This orientation can be saved in @position_orientation. Is it possible to show this triangle with a line in the middle and a predefined length for orientation in long distance? Or a live update of a placed point with live update symbology? This would be nice for finding a crossing point on a field boundry.
